# Node.js Async Loop to Query Database

Tags: node.js

I'm new to node.js.

I'm building a loop to query a database with chat messages every 3 seconds to then send required new messages to required users.

This is the loop I have - but currently it only loops once:

```
  // New Database Chat Messages Send
  var newDBMessagesInterval = 3000;     // 3 Seconds
  (function newDBMessagesSchedule() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      async(function() {
        console.log('async is done!');
        newDBMessagesSchedule();
      });
    }, newDBMessagesInterval)
  })();





function async() {
  console.log('in async function....');
}
```

Do I need to return something from the async function for the loop to continue?

Also is this a good/bad way to do a loop - my intention is to put a DB SELECT into the async function and don't what the DB calls to overlap.

Also is this non-blocking?

thx

Comment: I don't know what your situation is, but I think you might be going about your problem the wrong way. This sounds like you should be really using socketIO http://socket.io/ It will remove the necessity to query the database for new messages, and will be in real time.

Comment: I am using socket.io... but my connetions are spread across a few servers so I need to query DB and respond to required sockets... (eg: they don't all terminate on the same server...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing magical about aynchronous functions. You have to call the callback to an asynchronous function at some point. For testing purposes you should change `async` to:

```
function async(callback) {
  callback();
}
```

Yes, this is non-blocking.

However, from your comment, I see that you're doing this to send messages to sockets.  This isn't a great way to do that.  You should look into getting a "pub/sub" system, and having each server subscribe and publish their own messages.  Redis is a good choice for this.

Comment: thx - that works - my knowledge is slowly growing... appreciated.

Comment: @Adam Pleases see my edits.  I think you'll have an easier time with the pub/sub system I suggested.